# How to compare two subprocess output values in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

Python code:

```
filename = open("file.txt", "r")
subprocess.call(["./a.out" , "0-9"]), stdin= fin) #1
subprocess.call(["./a.out, "0123456789"], stdin = fin) #2
```

Here I wanted to compare the both commands by using if statement. 1) I have assigned to different variables and tried to compare it and it doesnt work. 2) I have also tried comparing on if statement (subprocess... == subprocess).

Please suggest me some solution

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Do you really want to use the same filehandle twice?  The second call will get only the data not read by the first.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre yes. I want to use the same file. I tried the solution you provided. I'm either getting the result as space or (' ', None).

Answer (score 1):

`call` doesn't capture output. It just returns the process return code. If both are 0, comparison always succeeds.

You need `check_output` instead:

```
output1 = subprocess.check_output(["./a.out" , "0-9"]), stdin= fin) #1
output2 = subprocess.check_output(["./a.out", "0123456789"], stdin = fin) #2

if output1 == output2:
    # do smth
```

`check_output` only returns the output if the command exits with a zero return code. If it's not the case, you'll have to use `subprocess.Popen` and read the output manually, or in python 3.5+ the generic `suprocess.run` call. Ex with `Popen`:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["./a.out" , "0-9"]), stdin= fin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #1
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["./a.out", "0123456789"], stdin = fin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) #2
output1 = p1.stdout.read()
output2 = p2.stdout.read()
rc1 = p1.wait()
rc2 = p2.wait()
```

now compare return codes & outputs.

Comment: It says subprocess.calledprocesserror: command '['./a.out','0-9',]' returend non-zero exit status 1

Comment: you have a non zero return code, as said in my answer `check_output` cannot work. Use `Popen`